# Create record using Model List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to create an invoice. I have two models, `Invoice` & `InvoiceItems`.

I am able to insert using hardcoded values, but I want to be able to use `TextBoxes` to create an invoice on the fly. How do I insert a record that takes the data for the invoice and the dynamic data from the invoice items and inserts into both tables, using the same view? I'd like to have an *add more* button eventually where I can stay on the same page and keep adding items to the same invoice.  You can see what I've tried so far below.

**Invoice Model:**

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Creation Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Due Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string InvoiceNotes { get; set; }

    public List<InvoiceDetails> InvoiceDetails { get; set; } 
    public List<Clients> Clients { get; set; } 
}
```

**InvoiceItem Model:**

```
public class InvoiceDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Item Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Item Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Qty")]
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Rate/Hour")]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Item Total")]
    public decimal? Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Invoice Controller:**

```
private NovaDb _db = new NovaDb();
public ActionResult InvoiceInformation()
    {
        var invoice = new Invoice();

        invoice.InvoiceDetails = new List<InvoiceDetails>();

        return View(invoice);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InvoiceInformation(Invoice model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var invoices = new Invoice()
            {
                Amount = model.Amount,
                CreationDate = model.CreationDate,
                DueDate = model.DueDate,
                InvoiceNotes = model.InvoiceNotes,
                InvoiceId = model.InvoiceId,
                ClientId = model.ClientId                    
            };

            _db.Invoices.Add(invoices);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Invoice View:**

```
@model NovaFinancial.Models.Invoice

@{
ViewBag.Title = "InvoiceInformation";
}

<h2>InvoiceInformation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Invoice</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvoiceId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNotes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNotes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceNotes)
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.InvoiceDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Name)    
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Note) 
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Quantity) 
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Price) 
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Total) 
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Name) | @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Note) | @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Note)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Quantity) | @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Quantity)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Price) | @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Price)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Total) | @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceDetails[i].Total)</td>
                </tr>
            }                
        </table>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Just wanted to check if you had made any progress on your problem.  It interests me, so I was spending a little time today working on it.  I can create an invoice with one item, but still trying to figure out how I can get multiple items to pass.  I do know that passing form inputs using the same name gives one an array, and I feel that might contain the key.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out "a" solution that might not be the best, but it works.  You'd still have to add to the code to make it more robust, but the general framework is there.

In your view, keep all the text boxes for the invoice details (Name, Quantity, Price) the same value for the name attribute, but do keep the id's unique.  I used a bit of jQuery and JavaScript to generate extra rows as needed per a button that the user would click.  For example,

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"> <!--first line item for Item Name-->
<input type="number" name="Quantity" id="Quantity"> <!--first for Quanitity -->

<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name2"> <!--second line item for Item Name-->
<input type="number" name="Quantity" id="Quantity2"> <!-- second for Quanitity -->
```

The values for the InvoiceDetail lines will pass back to the server as comma-delimited strings (better make certain that your item names don't have commas!).  On the server-side,

```
var Names = Request["Name"]; // this would yield something like "Labor,Parts"
```

In the controller, you'll need to parse the strings into arrays and create the instances of your InvoiceDetail from them.  I wrote a private method to split the strings and return a list of InvoiceDetail objects to the action method.  The onus is on you to validate this data:  both client-side and server-side need validation.

I did a few experiments.  You can see all the code here:  http://mefixme.blogspot.com/2014/10/aspnet-mvc-how-to-add-model-with.html

I hope that this helps you.